# Can't seem to backup

Tags: backup

I get this error message from Deja DUP backup program, does anyone know what to do about this?

> Giving up after 5 attempts. Error: g-io-error-quark: Error splicing
>   file: Input/output error (0)

Comment: "input/output", usually means storage device error!

Comment: What device are you backing up to? Specifically, what file system does it use?

Comment: I think I'm trying to back up to an external hard drive. To be honest it's so long ago I set this up I can't remember, it's not worked for months. And I don't know how to answer what file system it uses, is there some way you could tell me how to find out? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this error is already known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/1741458

> This bug affects 7 people
>   Déjà Dup  Confirmed   Undecided   Unassigned